# Does Armorer's Armor Modifications increase your Maximum number of infusions?

Tags: dnd-5e, artificer, artificer-infusions

So I was reading the Armorer's 9th level feature and came across this text

> In addition, the maximum number of items you can infuse at once increases by 2, but those extra items must be part of your Arcane Armor.

I didn't remember reading about a limit to the number of items you can infuse at one time so I went back to check the Infuse Item feature:

> You can infuse more than one nonmagical object at the end of a long rest; the maximum number of objects appears in the Infused Items column of the Artificer table.

So is this saying that a 9th level armorer could have 5 items infused at a time as opposed to the normal 3, provided 3 of those infusions are on the distinct pieces of their armor?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### A 9th level Armorer can have 3 infused items plus 2 additional infusions on their Arcane Armor, for a total of 5 infused items.

Consulting [the Artificer class feature table](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/artificer#TheArtificerTable), we see that a 9th level Artificer can have up to 3 items bearing infusions:

| Level | Proficiency Bonus | CLASS Features | Infusions Known | *Infused Items* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9th | +4 | Artificer Specialist Feature | 6 | ***3*** |

Then, the [Armorer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/artificer#Armorer)'s 9th level feature *Armor Modifications* states:

> In addition, the maximum number of items you can infuse at once increases by 2, but those *extra items* must be part of your Arcane Armor.

This increases the total number of infused items to 5, but the two extra must be on separate pieces of your Arcane Armor.

So from 9th level onward, an Armorer can have two more infused items than the number shown in the class feature table, as long as at least two of their infusions are on Arcane Armor pieces.

So you're reading of the rules here is *mostly* correct. When you state in the question:

> So is this saying that a 9th level armorer could have 5 items infused at a time as opposed to the normal 3, provided 3 of those infusions are on the distinct pieces of their armor?

The only correction is that only 2 of the infusions must be on Arcane Armor pieces.

Comment: Since the Artificer's _Infuse Item_ ability allows one Infusion only to be applied to each target item, it is worth mentioning that the Armorer's _Armor Modifications_ **also** allows the Arcane Armor to count as four different items.  Otherwise, the "but those [two] extra items must be part of your Arcane Armor" clause makes no sense.

Comment: @Kirt If it’s immediately obvious from the just reading the feature it doesn’t need to be mentioned. Both the question and the answer assume one has read the Armor Modifications feature.